# DotNet.HighCharts StepLine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'd start to use Dotnet.HighCharts controls to draw charts on my page in ASP.NET MVC app.
I used Google Charts, but they don't have enough functionality.

The task is to make charts with area ranges, step line and syncronized crosshair on multiple charts. Does DotNet.HighCharts do it?
By this time i did draw only area ranges.
If not, please give me a hint, which controls can do it.

```
 Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart())
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "July temperatures" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Type = AxisTypes.Datetime })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = string.Empty } })
            .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip
            {
                Crosshairs = new Crosshairs(true),
                Shared = true,
                ValueSuffix = "°C"
            })
            .SetLegend(new Legend())
            .SetSeries(new[]
            {
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Temperature",
                    Data = ChartsData.TemperatureVariationAverages,
                    ZIndex = 1,
                    Type = ChartTypes.Line,
                    PlotOptionsLine = new PlotOptionsLine
                    {

                        Marker = new PlotOptionsLineMarker
                        {
                            FillColor = Color.White,
                            LineWidth = 2,
                            LineColor = Color.Black
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Range",
                    Data = ChartsData.TemperatureVariationRanges,
                    Type = ChartTypes.Arearange,
                    ZIndex = 0,
                    PlotOptionsArearange = new PlotOptionsArearange
                    {
                        LineWidth = 0,
                        LinkedTo = ":previous",
                        Color = Color.Green,
                        FillOpacity = 0.1,
                    }
                },
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Range3",
                    Data = ChartsData.TemperatureVariationRanges1,
                    Type = ChartTypes.Arearange,
                    ZIndex = 0,
                    PlotOptionsArearange = new PlotOptionsArearange
                    {
                        LineWidth = 0,
                        LinkedTo = ":previous",
                        Color = Color.Red,
                        FillOpacity = 0.1,
                    }
                },
                                                        new Series
                {
                    Name = "Range2",
                    Data = ChartsData.TemperatureVariationRanges2,
                    Type = ChartTypes.Arearange,
                    ZIndex = 0,
                    PlotOptionsArearange = new PlotOptionsArearange
                    {
                        LineWidth = 0,
                        LinkedTo = ":previous",
                        Color = Color.Yellow,
                        FillOpacity = 0.1,
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have a look at the demos for [highstock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) and [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)

Comment: You can take a look at the logic of this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts and try to adjust it to  your needs.